# Certificate from Let's Encrypt fails to work with node.js

Tags: node.js, https

I try to read in a certificate generated with cerbot from Let's Encrypt and generate a https server with

```
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('key-certbot.pem','utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('csr-certbot.pem','utf8');
var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };   
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials);
```

It fails with this error message:

```
 _tls_common.js:88
      c.context.setCert(options.cert);
                ^

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:88:17)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:803:25)
    at new Server (https.js:54:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Desktop/TestHTTPS/test.js:16:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)

    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Solutions proposed somewhere else do not help:

- I do not want to generate and use a self signed certificate
- I don't see any illegal characters in my files
- Line endings are Unix-style x0A (\a) and should be compatible on my mac

What does it mean "no start line"?

Comment: Did you verify if the pem files are loaded correctly? The file csr-certbot.pem is the same of fullchain.pem created by certbot command? (I'm considering this tutorial https://medium.com/@yash.kulshrestha/using-lets-encrypt-with-express-e069c7abe625 as example)

Comment: What do you mean by "loaded correctly"? I exactly went along the tutorial https://blog.zackad.com/en/2017/08/19/create-websocket-with-nodejs.html which seems very the same.